# Why doesn't binding style my Vue component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```js
const EventLevelBoard = {
  name: "EventLevel",
  data: {
    levelStyle: {
      display: "block"
    },
    levelStyleinner: [
      { display: "block" },
      { display: "block" },
      { display: "block" }
    ]
  },
  template: `<ul class="eventlevel" v-bind:style="{data.levelStyle}">
    <li v-for="(item, idx) in eventlist" v-key="idx"  v-bind:style="levelStyleinner[idx]"><strong class="name">{{item.name}}</strong>
    <strong class="size">{{item.size}}</strong></li>
  </ul>`,
  props: {
    eventlist: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
};
```

Develop Console Error:

> data.levelStyle is undefined
>
> data.levelStyleinneris undefined

Why doesn't it find those data properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `data` is not an available property on the component instance, even though it is obviously defined in the *options*.

You can just access the data directly, like you did here:

```html
v-bind:style="levelStyleinner[idx]"
```

If you really want to access it through the instance, you could do so through `$data`:

```html
v-bind:style="$data.levelStyle"
```

There should be no curly braces `{ }` around the binding.